# What is the difference between view pagers and tapped activities?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I used both *view pagers* and *tabbed activities*, but I found that they do the same thing. My question is: **what is the difference between them?**

Comment: Do you mean to say "Tabbed Activity " ??

Comment: Yes sorry for the typo